# Azure Key Vault download certificate - bad data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

We are trying to download a certificate from az key vault.

I'll start with the error message:

```
Unhandled exception. Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Bad Data.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.CertificateClient.DownloadCertificate(DownloadCertificateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This error is thrown when the call to `DownloadCertificate` is made. Please note that I am setting the following: `X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet`.

The docs for `EphemeralKeySet` reads

> The key associated with a PFX file is created in memory and not persisted on    disk when importing a certificate.

Looking at the code for `DownloadCertificate` a new certificate is created using the certificates secret from the key vault see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/858b7ba9da51891ccb77b7aa88d94a44b9bffeb2/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates/src/CertificateClient.cs#L231)

`X509Certificate2 x509 = new(rawData, (string)null, options.KeyStorageFlags);`

Now, I have managed to get it working by adding the following config setting to my web app `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1` as per this [github page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Best-X509Certificate2-Practices).

Is there a way to get this working without loading a user profile (in-memory) or does the private key always need to be written to disk?